# How do I wire this inline rotary lamp dimmer

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, power-electronics, dimmer

I bought this to add dimming abilities to my table lamp... But after opening it up am not too sure where to solder the wires.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see 9 contacts. So you have 72 options for two wires or 432 for three.

Comment: Is this an AC or DC lamp? because that thing would probably start on fire if connected to AC.

Comment: @laptop2d ac... It says its rated for 250v 50hz ac

Comment: Post a schematic

Comment: This appears to be a very crude and utterly undocumented  diac-triggered triac dimmer for a ver low power AC resistive load given the tiny package of what could possibly be the triac.  It is not a finished product and not intended for end-user installation or use by anyone who does not have its specifications and limits.  You can readily buy packaged connectorized dimmers on the consumer market.

Comment: ebay? alibaba? amazon?

Comment: Read The Fine Manual, which you should have received had you bought this item from a reputable source.

Comment: There isn't adequate spacing on those PCB traces to carry AC, this board could be prone to arcing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at the rear view picture: top left terminal is one side; extreme right terminal is the other side.

This is assuming that the pot has a switch that turns OFF when the pot is at one extreme or the other (usually full Left).

Be aware that the triac appears to be tiny and will handle only a few watts of power.